# Name/Symbol for set of combinations without repetition

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, notation

Given a set $\mathcal{S}=\{1,2,3\}$, I'm interested in the set of all combinations of two elements without repetition:

$\{(1,2),(1,3),(2,3)\}$

Is there a name and symbol for such a set? Something like *Cartesian product* and $\times$?

I was wondering about $\binom{\mathcal{S}}{2}$, but I guess it is wrong since that is the usual way to define the number of combinations.

I should mention that elements are not necessary numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One usual notation is $[\mathcal S]^2$.

Generally, $[A]^n$ is the set of all the subsets of $A$ with exactly $n$ elements. One can also write $[A]^{<k}$ for all the sets with *less* than $k$ elements.

Comment: And $[A]^{\le k}$ for the collection of subsets of $A$ with at most $k$ elements. And in all of these notations $k$ can be an infinite cardinal as well as a finite one.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know of a document/website I can reference?

Comment: @caerolus: Jech **Set Theory** (3rd eds.) pp. 51-52.

Comment: Lifesaver...Cheers!